# Mixing C and objective-C

Tags: objective-c, c

I've been using objective C for a while now, and I've started learning some of the lower level iPhone API's such as core audio. Most of these API's are in C which is confusing me a bit, I'm not sure where to put a lot of code and I don't know the rules, etc. Does anyone know where a good place to start learning this is?

Thanks, Darren.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone know where a good place to start learning this is?

1. Buy and read "[The C Programming Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628)". It's not very long and surprisingly enjoyable.
2. Read and understand Apple's C-based example code.
3. Browse the header files for Apple's classes. This is a great way to learn how apple sets up `enum`s and string constants, etc.

Doing these three things won't make you an expert in C, but it'll give you 90% of what you need to be able to confidently get things done with Apple's low level frameworks.

Answer (score 6):

You can write C inline inside any Objective C method.  You can also define functions in a .c file and their prototypes in a .h file which you can then include into any ObjectiveC .m file and call from within Objective C code.

Comment: +1 for showing how to import native c code. I'm learning now and I've a good ammount of old C code that might be reusable. I've spent some time trying to find this on Apple's docs without success.

Answer (score 2):

Objective-C is a superset of classic C, which means you have access to *everything* C as well as *everything* implemented in Objective-C. You can write in both if you wish.